# How to match carriage return in java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

This is the regular expression I use, but it doesn't match string "%test\n###Hello". Could anyone help what's wrong in my regular expression ? Thanks

```
private static Pattern REPL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("%([\\w\\.]+).*");
```

Comment: It does not, due to the `.*` that only matches any number of chars *other than line break chars*. Use `Pattern.DOTALL` to make it match any char. Or `(?s)` embedded flag option (inline modifier).